# Minimum Travel Time

Tags: oracle

Display schedule_id, source, destination and travel_time which has minimum travel time. Sort the result based on schedule id.

I have tried this code and there is something missing in my query as I m getting the error.

[image: here is the schema for the query]

```
 select sh.schedule_id,sh.source,sh.destination,sh.duration as travel_time
         from schedule sh
         (select min(sh.duration) from schedule)
         order by sh.schedule_id;
```

Comment: The query itself is obviously wrong, but - you need help for *travel time* and posted model of *college management system*? How are those two related?

Comment: oops..sorry that is by mistake..now I have uploaded the correct schema.

Answer (score 1):

Almost correct. You forgot to define the minimum travel time in the where-clause.

```
SELECT   sh.schedule_id,
         sh.source,
         sh.destination,
         sh.duration as travel_time
FROM     schedule sh
WHERE    sh.duration = (select min(duration) from schedule) -- This is where the problem was.
ORDER BY sh.schedule_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Then only column which *looks like* travel time is `DURATION`, its datatype is `NUMBER`. What does that number represent? Minutes? Hours? Something else?

Anyway, here's one option you might consider. It "sorts" durations (i.e. "travel time") using `RANK` analytic function, and fetches a row (or rows) whose duration is minimal.

Advantage of such an approach is that you have to scan the table only once; if you select minimum duration in a subquery, and then use its result to fetch data you're interested in, you're accessing the same table twice which might matter when there are many rows involved. For a small sample data set, you won't notice any difference.

The `SCHEDULE` CTE represents some test data; you need code that starts at line 6.

```
SQL> with schedule (schedule_id, source, destination, duration) as
  2    (select 1, 'Paris', 'London'   , 8 from dual union all
  3     select 2, 'Berlin', 'Prague'  , 4 from dual union all
  4     select 3, 'Zagreb', 'Budapest', 4 from dual
  5    )
  6  select schedule_id, source, destination, duration
  7  from (select schedule_id, source, destination, duration,
  8           rank() over (order by duration) rn
  9        from schedule
 10       )
 11  where rn = 1;

SCHEDULE_ID SOURCE DESTINAT   DURATION
----------- ------ -------- ----------
          2 Berlin Prague            4
          3 Zagreb Budapest          4

SQL>
```

Comment: Everything will explode, @Robert. Boom! :) The author will be forced to use RANK instead of ROW_NUMBER. Fixed, thank you for the comment!

Comment: code that is starting from line 6 is passing only one test case

Comment: I don' understand what you mean. Feel free to provide your test case so that we wouldn't have to do that ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there was no need for alias names as you were accessing the data from the same table.

Code:

```
select 
    schedule_id,source,destination,duration from schedule
    where duration = (select min(duration) from schedule)
    order by schedule_id;
```